# Chartkick async providing min and max

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, chartkick

I'm using ChartKick and with the provided code:

```
<%= line_chart user_application_log_chart_path(@user_application)%>
```

Which should allow the line chart to make an ajax call to my endpoint to get the data on load of the page.

But i want to provide the min and max for the line chart based on the data i get.

How would i pass those params considering the only thing i can return from the ajax call is the JSON data.

I've tried supplying a json object with the structure:

```
{
    data: {//appropriate data},
    min: 240,
    max: 260
}
```

But that didn't work.